# ASP.NET Core How to output custom XML Model

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, formatting

I have a Web API built in C# core and I need to customize the XML output that one of my endpoints gives.

To configure my app to return XML and JSON, I use Accept Header like so:

```
        // Add framework services.
        services
            .AddMvc(options => {
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            })
            //support application/xml
            .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
            //support application/json
            .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });
```

And I have a model I return on a controller:

```
public class SageInvoice {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public long? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public long? JobId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }

    public decimal VAT { get; set; }

    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

The XML comes out like so:

```
<ArrayOfSageInvoice xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AutomotiveDTO.DTOs.SageIntegration">
    <SageInvoice>
        <Created>2017-03-15T11:09:34.21</Created>
        <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
        <Date>2017-03-15T00:00:00</Date>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <JobId>1</JobId>
        <Subtotal>100.00</Subtotal>
        <Total>120.00</Total>
        <VAT>20.00</VAT>
    </SageInvoice>
    <SageInvoice>
        <Created>2017-03-15T11:11:26.853</Created>
        <CustomerId>2</CustomerId>
        <Date>2017-03-15T00:00:00</Date>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <JobId i:nil="true"/>
        <Subtotal>23532.00</Subtotal>
        <Total>28238.40</Total>
        <VAT>4706.40</VAT>
    </SageInvoice>
</ArrayOfSageInvoice>
```

The consumer of my endpoint doesn't like it structured like this and wants me to make it look more:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order>
    <OrderSummary>
        <OrderID>1</OrderID>
        <OrderReference>ORDER1</OrderReference>
        <OrderDate>2017-03-15</OrderDate>
        <AccountNumber>ACCOUNT1</AccountNumber>
        <CompanyName>Company 1</CompanyName>
        <ContactTitle>Mr</ContactTitle>
        <ContactFirst>Dave</ContactFirst>
        <ContactLast>Dave</ContactLast>
        <Address1/>
        <Address2/>
        <Town/>
        <County/>
        <Postcode/>
        <Country/>
        <Telephone>01234567890</Telephone>
        <NumberOfItems>2</NumberOfItems>
        <OrderValue>200</OrderValue>
        <Downloaded>false</Downloaded>
    </OrderSummary>
    <OrderSummary>
    ...
    </OrderSummary>
</Order>
```

How can I change my XML output to match the above without wrecking the Accept headers JSON + XML input/output functionality?

Comment: you can use `[Xml...Atribute]` to change the name of the tag although `<Postcode/>` will ofcourse still be missing or you should add it to your class.

Comment: I've cut a lot of code out to try and simplify it tbf mate, but thank you I'll try that out if Tseng's answer doesn't work

Comment: @JoelHarkes What package do I need to access [Xml] mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)). The docs are for .NET Framework, but should also apply to .NET Core.

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Invoice", ItemName = "InvoiceSummary")]
public class SageInvoice
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What package do I need to install to get these namespaces friend?

Comment: I've added package to System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Added your attribute to the top of my class and I don't get any output at all.

Comment: DataMember and DataContract attributes also have no effect :/

Comment: Microsoft setup this wonderful site called "packagesearch" where you can do a reverse package search by searching by a type: http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=CollectionDataContractAttribute. CollectionDataContractAttribute is in System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives package, version 4.1.1 at least

Comment: When I install said package and add said attribute on my model I get 'GET http://localhost:52903/api/AcceptedInvoices net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' and a blank page?

Comment: any exceptions in the console window (if not hosting in IIS Express) or in the debug console inside Visual Studio (requires `AddDebug()` to be added, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#how-to-add-providers)

Comment: The exception hits my output window and not my debugger! mofos! Thank you so much. This is what I need! Thanks again :)